# Anyone know some good enough ways of handling encryption for a TCP server?

Tags: c#, encryption, tcp

I'm a hobby coder (no education). I have written a TCP server in C# NET 4.6 that can accept multiple clients, it works great, works like I want it to. However I want to encrypt some byte[] before sending it (the byte[]) between server and clients.

**I have thought about doing it a few ways**(*but I could really use some help*)**:**

- Have the AES encryption key in the source code of the server and the client. (but then the program exe can be decompiled)
- The server generates a new encryption key for each client that connects and sends the key unencrypted directly to the client. (but then the encryption key is sent unprotected over the internet, I dont know if thats a good way to do it).
- Every day there is a new encryption key, based on date (but that could cause trouble on different time zones).

I want to try to keep the data sent between server and clients over the internet as safe as possible :)

**I don't need help with any code, I just need a clever idea.**

*Thank you for all help!*

**ANSWER:** 
Thank you for all replies, I read all the articles and I now realize that cryptography is by far **out of my league**, I won't touch it. I'll just build my tcp server in a way so that there is nothing to hide.

Comment: You're trying to re-invent TLS.  Don't do that.  Instead, use TLS/SSL.

Comment: Also, read https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe/

Comment: A secure connection is useless unless you have some way to identify who is at the other end of it. (What good is a secure connection to a bad guy's server rather than good guy's server?) The first step to answering your question is to figure out how the identification of the end point is going to work.

Comment: SLacks is correct - "reinventing the wheel" is a Bad Thing in general ...but it's *catastrophic* when it comes to "security".  Here are a few alternatives: [TLS/SSL and .NET Framework 4.0](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/tlsssl-and-.net-framework-4.0/), [Using SSL over TCP as client and server with C#](http://www.dib0.nl/code/343-using-ssl-over-tcp-as-client-and-server-with-c) or [SslStream Class (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: To elaborate on my "catastrophic" remark: [Information Security: Why shouldn't we roll our own?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own), and [You are dangerously bad at cryptography](https://www.happybearsoftware.com/you-are-dangerously-bad-at-cryptography.html).  Both links are enlightening - satisfaction guaranteed!

Comment: Thank you for all replies, I read all the articles and I now realize that cryptography is by far **out of my league**, I won't touch it. I'll just build my tcp server in a way so that there is nothing to hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encryption is **really difficult** to get right. You can make easy-to-make mistakes that are really, really difficult to see. Big companies with competent and knowledgeable programmers have made simple errors that ruined their encryption.

If you want to keep the data as safe as possible, use a well-tested encryption library that provides the functions you need.

---

On that note, if you'd just like to learn more by programming without it being very safe, you can distribute session keys using a different kind of encryption called public key encryption.

The server will have a private key that only exists on the server. The corresponding public key will be included in all clients. Only the server will be able to read messages encrypted using the public key.

The client will generate a new AES encryption key when it starts up. It will send that to the server using public key encryption. Then they'll both know what key the client came up with and they can communicate from then on using AES.

Comment: Thank you for all replies, I read all the articles and I now realize that cryptography is by far **out of my league**, I won't touch it. I'll just build my tcp server in a way so that there is nothing to hide.